# html with inline dynamic javascript written by php syntax issue

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
$i = 1
$k = "a link or an url"
$value = "The'.$i.'Item"
$getID = "object.getObjectById('object')";
$function = ".newAddress({"f->'.$k.'}{s->0}")";  

// to pass a newAddress to Object

$out = $getID.$function; // Combine two function together
```

I tried to `object.getObjectById('name').newAddress`
But because the syntax I am messing up right now

```
$b.= "<a id='air_".$i."' onclick=".$out.">".$value."</a>";
```

So, I want the output should be like

```
<a id='air_0' onClick="object.getObjectById('object').newAddress('{f->'$k'}{s->0}')" />
```

Comment: that's javascript-in-html-in-php, meaning you have to escape the JS from **BOTH** html and php...

Comment: Notice that your first 3 lines are missing semi-colons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will simplify the problem if you write the JS out more plainly and concatenate the PHP variables into it. I used the backslash to escape single quotes inside the PHP single quotes.

See if this does what you need it to do.

```
<?php
$i = 1;
$k = "a link or an url";
$value = "The'.$i.'Item";
$out='<a id="air_'.$i.'" onClick="object.getObjectById(\'object\').newAddress(\'{f->\''.$k.'\'}{s->0}\')" />The '.$i.' item </a>';
echo $out;
```

[See it in the sanndbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d3069fd718f84745cf5bd0b0faf36ab11af9789c)